# Google Drive / Google Docs API Echo Changes in Version History

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-docs

I have connected to the Google API. Specifically Google Docs / Google Drive through the google OAUTH 2.0.

I am able to get this information. When AUTHED with the google client [Information Given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGUv0.png) This information tells me Revision ID and Revision Date. I am using PHP /Composer for all decencies and code. I am trying to collect the specific information changed in the version date.

For Example, PHP echo out text Added / or a style CSS Color of Red for example. That would echo out text removed and GREEN css for text added on the document for each revision date. I have provided code with where I am at.

I do not know if the GOOGLE API / Reference allows me to do this at all. But it would be awesome if someone can show me the correct way to show the specific changes from the words removed/added to the images IF added, through a Javascript / HTML button for each revision DATE/TIME or ID.

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');  // Path to your client_secrets.json file
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Docs::DOCUMENTS_READONLY);
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php');  // Path to your OAuth 2.0 callback file

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // Query to get Google Documents owned by the user
    $optParams = array(
        'q' => "'me' in owners and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.document'",
        'fields' => 'files(id, name)',
    );

    $results = $driveService->files->listFiles($optParams);

    if (count($results->getFiles()) == 0) {
        print "No Google Documents found.\n";
    } else {
        $userInfo = $driveService->about->get(['fields' => 'user']);
        $googleUsername = $userInfo->getUser()->getDisplayName();

        echo "Hello : " . $googleUsername . "<br><br>";

        print "Google Documents:<br>";
        foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
            printf("Document: %s (%s)<br>", $file->getName(), $file->getId());

            $revisions = $driveService->revisions->listRevisions($file->getId());
            foreach ($revisions->getRevisions() as $revision) {
                $modTime = $revision->getModifiedTime();
                echo "Revision ID: " . $revision->getId() . ", Modified Time: " . $modTime . "<br>";
            }

            echo "<hr>"; // Add a horizontal rule
        }
    }
} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';  // Path to your OAuth 2.0 callback file
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
?>
```

Unable to get information needed.